# Passing reference of current JFrame to JDialog in an action listener

Tags: java

Suppose I have JFrame with one button on it, and JDialog which should have reference to that JFrame. When user clicks on button, I need to open JDialog, but I need to pass **this** which is referencing JFrame. So I made action listener on that button, but I cannot use this in that context, because it is referencing action listener, not a JFrame( which is logical, because it is in listener block). Any suggestion?

```
public class App extends JFrame{
private JButton btnAdd;
public App(){}
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       AppDialog app =new AppDialog (this); // this cannot be used here
        }}
```

```
 public class AppDialog extends JDialog {
App app;    
public AppDialog(App app){
this.app = app;}
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Mat I have edited question with code blocks.

Comment: Found solution --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981623/how-to-reference-jframe/23981838